# Convert a string containing hex (along with other characters) to binary in Python

Tags: python, string, binary, hex

I have a file containing lines of `something.something(hexvalue1,hexvalue2)`

I am trying to convert these hexvalues to binary. From what I researched I figured out I will have to search for hex values in each line and then convert them to binary. I am not sure how to do the search in a string for hex values with other variables in it. 
Note : All the lines are in the same format.

When I do :

```
for line in file:
    string = line
    string.split('(')
```

does not split at the '('

Comment: Are you looking for hex value arguments to functions? (ie, are you working on source code), if not - what? Also, why do you want to do this exactly?

Comment: Can you provide a real example line?

Comment: I am trying to do this so that I can feed this value to another system and this system accepts only binary input. I am writing a script which will take an input file parse it and print the required lines (the one with these hex values) into an output file. I am converting the hex values in the output file to binary and assigning it to two variables.

Comment: I am at step 2. I have parsed the file. I have the lines, I have converted it to binary. I dont want to post the entire script in the forum so just gave the part which will convert the hex to binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, all string methods return new objects (they *have* to since strings are an immutable type).  `str.split` returns a `list`.  So to parse your string, it would be something like:

```
for line in file:
    left,right = line.split('(',1)
    hexvalues = right.split(')')[0]
    hex1,hex2 = hexvalues.split(',')
```

For those more inclined toward regular expressions:

```
import re
>>> re.findall(r'\(([^)]+)',"this.is(0xffaabb,0x112214)")
['0xffaabb,0x112214']
```